# How do I unlock new uniforms in COD: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I don't like the uniform I have in *Call of Duty: Ghosts*.  I want something that's harder to see.

How do I unlock new uniforms for my soldier?

Comment: Just find a hack like all the other CoD jackwagons

Answer (score 2):

You unlock them by completing challenges.  Find one that you like and work out what challenge is associated with it.  For instance, the Ghillie suit needs you to make 850 kills using a sniper rifle with a chrome barrel.  (Choose the one with in-built steady aim to counterbalance the additional sway caused by the heavier barrel)

Then, check your operations and make sure that you have the appropriate challenge listed there.  You may need to change your operations a few times until you have the mix you want.  Note that it costs 1 squad point to "re-roll" them and you'll get a random selection each time.

When you have the challenge you need, click on it to highlight.  That'll "lock" it so it'll not be randomised.  You can only lock one challenge in each of the five sections locked.

When you've unlocked your uniform, go to "Create a soldier" and then choose the "Customise" option.  This is F2 by default on the PC.  Go to "Special" at the top of the list and select your Ghillie suit.

Here, you can select a uniform.  Job done.

Comment: This is why I've lost interest in Ghosts.  Why does that have to be so complicated!